# JQuery AutoComplete Feature Stops Working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the following code for autocomplete feature. The code was working fine before but as I copy it to another aspx page, the code stops working.

I have gone through many of the previously asked questions on the same but I found nothing. This **[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106029/asp-net-jquery-autocomplete-textbox-not-responding-after-first-search)** helped me little but doesn't solve my problem.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "PGForBoys.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'location':'" + document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The function code is:

```
[WebMethod]

    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string location)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\RoomRentDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security
         =True;User Instance=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT Location from Details where Location LIKE '%'+@location+'%'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["Location"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there an error? what is returned from the server? does the `d` in `data.d` contain an object built like, `{label: some text, value: some value}`?

Comment: No there is no error, the code is working fine on a single aspx page but as I copy it to another page in the same website, it stops working. Is there something like JQuery code can be used only once in a site?

Comment: I have got my solution, thanks for the interest you show.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer so you can potentially help others who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I catch the silly mistake myself. Actually I was not changing the url of the page and thus it was not reading my function and hence not showing the results.

I have to change `url: "PGForBoys.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData"`for every page I am using the code.